# why I am getting, cannot read property of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This  code

```js
function Test(){

}
new Test()



['width', 'height'].forEach(key => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

gives me error

[image]

but this code not

```js
function Test(){

}
new Test()

var arr = ['width', 'height'];
arr.forEach(key => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

**why?**

I am using chrome
Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit) -  Macbook air 2014

Comment: I just tried your first example in Chrome 58; can't reproduce. Which browser are you using?

Comment: This code should work fine and I just tried in on Chrome 58 and it works

Comment: Please refer [browser compatibility](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=foreach) for `aray.forEach`

Comment: @Rajesh saying the error 'cannot read property forEach of undefined', maybe the problem is with the declaration of the array "on-the-fly", not with forEach itself

Comment: @Aurora0001 -  I am using chrome 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)

Comment: @quirimmo given the code snapshot, my bet is there is unterminated line and minification make it look like `<someCode>['width', 'height'].forEach`. Now `<someCode>[...]` will return `undefined` and hence error

Comment: @rajesh totally agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've omitted whatever is actually causing the problem from your code.

Immediately before the `[` you must have something which refers to an object.

This means that the `[]` syntax becomes the syntax to read a property value instead of the syntax to create an array.

Then (because you are using a comma operator) `'width', 'height'` resolves as `'height'` so you are trying to read the `height` property.

Since there is no `height` property on whatever the object is, you get `undefined` which doesn't have a `forEach` property.

To fix this **put a semicolon at the end of the previous statement**.

The second version of your code works because the `var` statement can't follow the syntax you have just before it, so it triggers *automatic semicolon insertion*.

Answer (score 2):

As per snapshot, you are using chrome and Chrome supports `.forEach` from a long time. My guess is, issue is due to minification or missing semicolon(`;`)

**Sample**

```js
function test(){
  this.name = "test";
}

var a = new test()['width', 'height'].forEach(key => {
  console.log(key);
});
```